# Zoom Issue in Safari - why does Border-top fix it, and is there another way?

Tags: html, css, safari

I've come across a strange issue that I'm only experiencing in Safari (7 on Mac - don't know about Windows).

When the user zooms **out**, a space appears above the header.  At 100% (no zoom), or zooming in, there is no space.

From experience in the past, I decided to try adding padding-top (didn't work), and border-top, which **did** work.

So - I'm hoping that someone here can explain to me:

1. Do you know why border-top fixes this?
2. Is this a Safari bug, or am I misunderstanding something?
3. Is there a *better way* to fix this? A border-top is going to be problematic for this particular client,
   and I'd like to find a cleaner solution.

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="headerwrapper">
            <div id="headerliner">
                <header>
                    <nav class="menu">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Top Level Menu Item</a>
                                <ul class="sub-menu"><li><a href="#" >Child Menu Item</a></li></ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </header>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#headerwrapper {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#headerliner {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
header {
    background: black;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 1px 0 0 0;
    /* Remove the below line, and the space appears in Safari */
    border-top: 1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: I haven't actually tested your issue in Safari, but are you aware that the `<html>` tag is missing in the code you posted? Not sure if that is a copy+paste error or if it is causing something weird to happen in Safari.

Comment: @SombreErmine - great observation.  That was a typo - thanks for catching it.  Unfortunately, the issue still exists even with the html tag.

Comment: Could it be from the `<ul>` tag? Since it has a default margin ([default styles](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/sample.html)) and when I put your code into jsfiddle, your header expands the `padding: 1px 0 0 0;` to the top of the `<ul>` top margin.

Comment: Setting the margin-top to 0 on the ul tag does solve it.  However, the issue I am facing on the full production version of this code is that the nav is supposed to be 36px down from the top of the header / wrapper element, so that margin is specific, intentional, and necessary.  And, this causes me to wonder - why only when zooming? Why only on Safari? Why doesn't the padding-top on the container resolve it (which it does in other situations / browsers)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Is there a better way to fix this?

To find out a way to fix this other than using some `border-top` hack, let's inspect the element and find out the root cause of the problem. The reason why there is a space above when you zoom out is because by default, Safari gives `margin-top: 16px` and `margin-bottom: 16px` to `<ul>` elements.

[image: ul margin analysis]

So to fix it, simply do

```css
ul {
    margin-top: 0;
}
```

See [full page demo](http://fiddle.jshell.net/zkv9Y/2/show/light/). ([fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/zkv9Y/2/))

As per you comment:

> the issue I am facing on the full production version of this code is that the nav is supposed to be 36px down from the top of the header / wrapper element, so that margin is specific, intentional, and necessary

You can always use `padding-top` on your `<nav>` element instead of `margin-top` on `<ul>` ([demo](http://fiddle.jshell.net/zkv9Y/4/show/light/)).

```css
nav.menu {
    padding-top: 36px;
}
```

### Why does border-top fixes this? Is this a Safari bug?

To know why `border-top` fixes it, lets take a look at the [W3C specifications on collapsing margins](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins):

> #### Collapsing margins
>
> In CSS, the adjoining margins of two or more boxes (which might or
>   might not be siblings) can combine to form a single margin. ...
>   Adjoining vertical margins collapse... Horizontal margins never
>   collapse.
>
> Two margins are adjoining if and only if ... both belong to in-flow
>   block-level boxes that participate in the same block formatting
>   context no line boxes, no clearance, no padding and no border separate
>   them ...

Here is a comparison of the two cases with respect to `<header>` and `<ul>`.

[image: comparison]

Without the border, there is nothing to separate the `margin-top` of the `<header>` (parent) and that of `<ul>` (child), and [the collapsed margin ends up outside the parent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin_collapsing), causing the white space to appear. However, with a `border-top` to separate them, the margins no longer collapses and the `margin-top` of `<ul>` ends up inside the parent, and the space disappears.

Comment: Fantastic answer, thank you.  In reading it, I wonder a couple of things: does the fact that FF / Chrome do no exhibit this behavior represent a bug in their rendering? And any idea why this only comes into play on zoom in, not at no zoom (100%) or zoom out?

Comment: @cale_b This behavior actually occurs on [Firefox](http://i.stack.imgur.com/TbdXL.png) and [Chrome](http://i.stack.imgur.com/7PbPY.png) as well, with the only difference being that the `padding: 1px 0 0 0;` you set on `<header>` is enough to break collapsing margins in Firefox and Chrome, but Safari needs `padding: 2px 0 0 0;` in order to break that. Probably another browser inconsistency regarding the default style. So why does this only occur in zoom? Actually no. Firefox and Chrome shows a space when there is no `padding-top` or `border-top` without zoom. Remove the padding and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use an overall CSS Reset?  I highly recommend it, and use them on ALL of my CSS based themes.  I'm not saying this will fix it per say, but there is always the chance.  By default, not EVERY browser is the same, and you will run into errors a long the way.

Comment: I do use a reset, yes.  Good tip, but not a specific answer to the specifics of this question.

Comment: Yeah sorry about that, like I said, I didn't know if it would help you or not.  Just throwing in my little tid bit about doing CSS Resets as they can save headaches :)  but not always.